# Azure Virtual 1280 x 800 and can't change

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure

My Azure virtual is 1280 x 800, and on my laptop when I RDP in, it's really cramped on space as my apps are blown up really large.  I don't know why this happened all of a sudden; the only difference I can think of is I was on a surface, but now a laptop... but why won't it go to full screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  Stopping and Starting it flushed the configuration, and now it is back to full size.